# probability of sequential events

Tags: probability

something has to travel from A to B. between these points there are two stages, where at each one it can fail with a probability of 0.3.

what is the total probability that the thing successfully travels from A to B?

Comment: Note that it can fail either right away at point 1 (you know the probability of that) or (with probability that it does not fail at point 1) it can fail at point 2 with a probability that you know. Add these to get total probability of failure, F, then 1-F is the probability of success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume that two stages are independent, then probability of success is multiplication of success of each stage.
Hence $P = 0.7*0.7 = 0.49.$

Comment: they are independent, but they are sequential. so if it fails at the first one, it doesnt even get to the second one.

Comment: @clamp thats right. What I have mentioned is short cut. You can also find probability of failure which is $0.3*0.3$(fail in both stages) + $2*0.3*0.7$(fail in one stage but pass in other). Now subtract it by 1. You will get $1 - (0.09 + 0.42) = 0.49.$

Answer (score 0):

I'll call your "it" a "car" and I'll assume that if the car fails at stage 1, then the car does not reach stage 2.

Presumably, the probability that the car fails at the second stage *given* that the car did not fail at the first stage is $0.3$. (Note then  that if $S_1$ is the event "the car fails at stage 1" and $S_2$ is the event "the car fails at stage 2", then $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not independent.)

Let

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S_1$ be the event that the car fails at stage 1,

and let

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S_2$ be the event that the car fails at stage 2.

You can use the multiplication rule to find the probability that the car makes the journey: 
$$
P(S_1^C\cap S_2^C)=P(S_1^C)P(S_2^C\mid S_1^C)=(0.7)(0.7)=.49.
$$

Or, you can argue as follows:

Noting that $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$ and that $S_2\subset S_1^C$, the probability that the journey is unsuccessful is
$$\eqalign{
P(S_1 \cup S_2)&=P(S_1)+P(S_2)\cr
&=P(S_1)+P(S_2\cap S_1^C )\cr
&= P(S_1)+P(S_2|S_1^C )P(S_1^C)\cr
&=(0.3)+(0.3)(0.7)\cr
&=0.51.
}
$$
So the probability that the car makes the journey  is $1-0.51=0.49$.